# What is the best way to integrate MVC 3 html helpers with twitter boostrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my radiobuttons to look like regular buttons (like the button groups here:http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/components.html).  The problem is if I use the razor html helper @Html.RadioButtonFor(... I don't understand how to link that output with the  elements that the bootstrap requires.  What is the best way to go about putting the data into the bootstrap styling without losing the razor linking to my model?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Have you looked at using templates? `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` then using `DisplayFor`/`EditorFor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with writing out the radio buttons "long hand" in normal Html `<Input type="radio">` syntax, especially if it's a one off and you have custom bits of Html to go round it. The HtmlHelpers are only that, helpers. Just make sure you populate the `id="model.value"` so the binder picks up the property.

If you find yourself re-using this longer code then you could create an HtmlHelper extension method to render the Html you want. It's kind of like building your own one and would allow you to do something like `Html.TwitterRadioButtonFor(....)`.

There is a very basic guide to writing HtmlHelpers on [this](http://mstecharchitect.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/extending-aspnet-mvc-htmlhelper-class.html) blog.

EDIT: If you are just looking to style then you can always just pass in a class using

```
new { @class = "myClass" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to integrate html helpers with twitter bootstrap is to use [TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/)

-- Free for Bootstrap 2.